# AutoCompleteTextView is showing wrong results

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, autocompletetextview

here it is : I'm typing "di", but AutoCompleteTextView is showing me unrelated stuff.

[image]

Here's how I init this :

```
autocompleteAdapter = new AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter(MainActivity.activity,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, autoCompleteStrings);
etSearch.setAdapter(autocompleteAdapter);
```

And here's my Adapter (I tried standard ArrayAdapter but result was the same)

```
class AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    Activity main;
    int rowLayout;
    List<String> strings;

    private ArrayList<String> originalValues;
    private ArrayFilter filter;

    public AutoCompleteDropdownAdapter(Activity main, int rowLayout, List<String> strings) {
        super(main, rowLayout, strings);
        this.main = main;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.strings = strings;
        originalValues = new ArrayList<String>(strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        private Object lock;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (originalValues == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    originalValues = new ArrayList<String>(strings);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(originalValues);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<String> values = originalValues;
                int count = values.size();

                ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String item = values.get(i);
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(item);
                    }

                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        if(results.values!=null){
            ArrayList<String> tempStrings = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            strings.clear();
            strings.addAll(tempStrings);
        }else{
            strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
```

now, when I debug the publishResults method it shows me exactly 2 results I need , but nevertheless, AutoCompleteTextView drops down wrong list

Comment: do you using inflater and set text to your dropdown item?Add all code of adapter if you skipped something

Comment: no, it's just super.getView()

Answer (score 0):

class ArrayFilter extends Filter :

change :
        if (item.toLowerCase().contains(prefixString)) {

to:
        if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefixString)) {

Answer (score -1):

I think you can find some hints from this example:

https://github.com/gabu/gabubon2/blob/master/src/net/gabuchan/androidrecipe/recipe033/Recipe033Activity.java#L14

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_033);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    AutoCompleteTextView v = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text_view);
    v.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    AutoCompleteTextView v = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text_view);
    Toast.makeText(this, v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```